# Make centered auto-overflow div take remaining space in bootstrap 4.1.3

Tags: bootstrap-4

I´m forced to use bootstrap 4.1.3 and would like to achieve a middle aligned div that takes remaining space and auto-overflows it´s content. So that the footer and header stays fixed. Like in this example which uses the latest bootstrap (4.3.1):
https://jsfiddle.net/x47z1qsv/

Now the exact same example in bootstrap 4.1.3 doesent work, and I cannot figure out why: https://jsfiddle.net/69g0yhj8/

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex h-100 flex-column">
    <div class="row flex-shrink-0">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h5>Header</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bg-primary flex-fill d-flex overflow-auto">

        <div class="col-12">
           Start<br/>
           Line of text<br/>
           Line of text<br/>
           Line of text<br/>
           Line of text<br/>
           Line of text<br/>             
           Line of text<br/>
           End<br/>           
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flex-shrink-0">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h5>Footer</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? I see no difference in both of them

Comment: If you scroll in the blue column, the footer and header is fixed in the first example, but not in the second example.

Comment: Both the fiddles are using Bootstrap 4.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow-auto` class doesn't exist in bootstrap 4.1.3

Add it in your custom CSS if you want to use it

```
.overflow-auto {
    overflow: auto!important;
}
```

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tx83jbwf/1/)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.overflow-auto {
  overflow: auto!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid d-flex h-100 flex-column">
  <div class="row flex-shrink-0">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h5>Header</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row bg-primary flex-fill d-flex overflow-auto">

    <div class="col-12">
      Start<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/>      Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/>      Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> Line of text<br/> End
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row flex-shrink-0">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h5>Footer</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```